# What's the difference between these two F# sequences?

Tags: syntax, f#

```
> seq { for i in 0..3 do yield float i };;
val it : seq<float> = seq [0.0; 1.0; 2.0; 3.0]
> seq [ for i in 0..3 do yield float i ];;
val it : seq<float> = [0.0; 1.0; 2.0; 3.0]
```

P.S. why did F# originally expect sequences without the "seq" prefix, but now they want the prefix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More clarification on the two forms you posted:

The first one uses a direct sequence comprehension, "seq { ... }". The "seq" part was optional before, but that's not going to be supported in the future. I guess it makes things like "async { ... }" and the workflow syntax more difficult or something.

Now, the second one is a pure list:

```
> let x = [ for i in 0..3 do yield float i ];;

val x : float list
```

"seq" is also a function:

```
> seq;;
val it : (seq<'a> -> seq<'a>) = <fun:clo@0_1>
```

And since any list is also a sequence, doing "seq [1;2;3;]" is just applying the seq function to the list. It's sorta like casting it to seq from the list type.

```
> x;;
val it : float list = [0.0; 1.0; 2.0; 3.0]

> seq x;;
val it : seq<float> = [0.0; 1.0; 2.0; 3.0]
```

Edit: The source for the seq function is:

```
let seq (x : seq<_>) = (x :> seq<_>)
```

So, "sorta like casting it" should read "casting it via a helper function". As for the printing of sequences inside brackets, I think that's just a pretty printing artifact.

Comment: It's confusing that the interpreter says that "seq { for i in 0..3 do yield float i };;" has a value of "seq [0.0; 1.0; 2.0; 3.0]", yet if you type "seq [0.0; 1.0; 2.0; 3.0];;" directly, the interpreter says it has a value of "[0.0; 1.0; 2.0; 3.0]".

Comment: Is applying the seq function "sort of" like casting to seq (=IEnumerable), or is it F#'s direct equivalent of a cast?

Comment: Or, does F# have a separate cast operator?

Comment: F#'s cast operators are :> for upcasts and :?> for downcasts.

Answer (score 3):

The first is a seq (IEnumerable).

The second is weird; get rid of the 'seq' and it's a list comprehension (list).  There's no reason to write it as is; either use seq{ } or [ ] or [| |] to make a seq or a list or an array.

The curlies-not-prefixed-by-seq is a form that will be deprecated, as it makes some other parts of the language potentially ambiguous.

Comment: I'm too newbie to know the difference between the first and second forms. Would you mind clarifying?

Comment: The second form is really a list, as noted by the [ ]. seq just turns it into a sequence after it's been generated as a list.